# Why aren't some of these SCP Policies working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-scp

I have an Org with ROOT + Management Account and TWO Accounts that inherit from Root: Development and Production. In the Development Account I'm creating the following SCPs:

0. I have DETACHED the default **FullAwsAccess**
1. SCP will ONLY deny any RDS action (create, delete etc) --- WORKS
2. SCP will ONLY allow EC2 to CREATE EC2s if it has the correct tags values --- WORKS
3. SCP will ONLY allow to CREATE EC2s if it has the correct tag keys--- DOESNT WORK

Am trying to understand why the final SCP is having no effect. I can put ANY tag named say "FOOO" It doesnt matter WHAT tag I put in (its supposed to fail since i dont have BOTH "ENV" & "OwnerContact" tabs, but its still allowing me to launch the EC2 Instance. As opposed to say the second SCP which fails correctly if I dont put in the ENV tag with either DEV/QA/PROD!!

**SCP FullAWSAccess Detached**

**SCP 1 Attached (Works)**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAllAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyRDSAccess",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "rds:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**SCP 2 Attached (Works)**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowLaunchEC2OnlyWithENVTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:RequestTag/ENV": [
            "DEV",
            "QA",
            "PROD"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**SCP 3 Attached (Doesn't Work)**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AlowOnlySpecificTags",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": [
            "ENV",
            "OwnerContact"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```